# Accessing file upload control placed in user control from the parent ASP.Net page

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, user-controls

I've a file upload control in my asp.net user control. This user control is being used in a asp.net page. I want to access the file path selected through this control in my parent page. I'm aware that for user controls, we need to make public properties in code behind which are then available to parent. I wrote the below code in the code behind of user control to make a public property for file path

```
  public string TCSnippetFilePath
            {
                get
                {
                    return Path.GetFullPath(fuTCSnippet.PostedFile.FileName);
                }
                set
                {
                    Path.GetFullPath(fuTCSnippet.PostedFile.FileName) = value;
                }
            }
```

fuTCSnippet is the ID of File Upload control

This code is giving me below error:
The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer

Any inputs on what needs to be done?

Answer (score 0):

you cant assing value to fileupload control you can get the file name

```
  public string TCSnippetFilePath
            {
                get
                {
                    return Path.GetFullPath(fuTCSnippet.PostedFile.FileName);
                }
             // not need to set properties value
            }
```

beacause `FileUpload` Control  Properties `HttpPostedFile` have only get value you can't assing `HttpPostedFile` to `Fileupload`control